# Batch command to edit filestream

Tags: windows, batch-file, filestream

'echo 0 > Q:\FactoryRecovery\RECOVERY.INI:Done'

Can anyone please explain to me how this command works? I'm curious after reading this Superuser post: https://superuser.com/questions/384658/why-can-i-only-create-one-factory-backup-from-my-lenovo-thinkpad

It allows you to create more than one recovery disk.

Comment: Google for `alternate data stream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, heres a brief expanation:

```
Echo 0
```

Simply outputs `0` to the screen. Thats not to complicated. adding a `>>` and a file path after this will **redirect** the output to the **end** of the file. Adding a `>` will replace the contents of the file with what is being redirected.

Hence:

```
Echo 0 > Q:\FactoryRecovery\RECOVERY.INI
```

Will replace the contents of `Recovary.INI` with `0`(while it used to be `1`).
It prevents the file needed to create additional recovary disks from exiting, essentially allowin you to create more than one.

Mona.

Comment: It uses `alternate data stream` to write the info and is not just as you've described it.

Comment: You forgot the really important part: " echo 0 > Q:\FactoryRecovery\RECOVERY.INI **:Done** "